# How does the CLR manages a delegate that is part of an object and the object lifecycle ends?

Tags: c#, delegates, clr, lifecycle

I have to do an async callback handler in a distributed system architecture.

What happens if I assign a delegate that is part of an object in a certain layer, but the object is a local, will the CLR keep the reference until the functionality that it is handling is alive, or will it die like a function pointer would do (and point to a memory location that could be anything)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegates function under the same rules as any other object. You can never observe the fact that a delegate or any other object is collected.

What do you mean by "the object is a local"? In .NET objects are never stack-allocated. Objects do not go away when a stack frame is destroyed.

Comment: Thats it, objects are not stack-allocated. Thank you I just started using .NET